# MCVE shortcut link in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, help-center

Many of the [shortcut links to help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) work in chat, including [`[ask]`, `[answer]`, `[main]`, and `[meta]`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37328576#37328576). This is a very useful feature. However, `[mcve]` does not work. Can we get the `[mcve]` shortcut in chat? While you are at it, enable the `help/*` links as well.

Comment: have you been able to try the other shortcuts in chat? do they work? I know `tag` works..

Comment: @suraj further testing shows that not all the links are parsed: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37328576#37328576

Comment: the number of times I've had to go look for the MCVE link instead of just type `[mcve]` in chat is a number >5. And the number of times I *could* have, is probably >50.

Comment: This would be fantastic. The process of 1. open tab 2. look up "mcve stackoverflow" 3. copy link 4. past link back in chat. 5. question why I do this.....is not fun.

Comment: @idjaw or you could just bookmark it, saving a few steps. Still, the shortcut syntax would be very helpful.

Comment: this is even more urgently needed now that the mentoring system is online!

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244720/site-specific-magic-comment-links

Answer (score 7):

There's a userscript for this now:

#### [ChatMoreMagicLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatMoreMagicLinks.user.js) ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ChatMoreMagicLinks.user.js))

List of additional magic links handled by this userscript:

- `[mcve]`
- `[help]`
- `[help/on-topic]`
- `[help/dont-ask]`
- `[help/behavior]`
- `[meta-help]`
- `[tour]`
- `[chat]`

---

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

Comment: Nice.. Thank you. I suggest adding a post in https://stackapps.com

Comment: I pray for the day my organisation allows extensions

Comment: Unfortunately though, this requires installation for it to work. Which means any users without the extension won't see it (and these users are probably the majority)

Comment: @Zoe I do what I can do to help, something is probably better than none at all