# Can shorthand tags work in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, minimal-reproducible-example

Commenting on the website I often link to the "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page" when asking for clarification.

People come to chat and request help with various questions. They sometimes need a few questions of ping-pong with room denizens in order to formulate a coherent question and we link to it pretty commonly.

Since [2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294563/can-we-have-mcve-expand-to-http-stackoverflow-com-help-mcve-in-comments-ple) just typing `[mcve]` generates a nice link to that page.

Could typing `[mcve]` in chat expand the same way it does on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Thanks for finding the dupe @vaultah - appreciate it!

Comment: I'd have thought doing this for chat.SO would be fairly straightforward. I'm guessing though that if the chat code is all the same for the different instances...they don't want to fork the code specifically for here and then there's the question of what happens on chat.SE. Then it'll probably open the door of if different sites can have their own markdown shortcuts etc...(while the other chat links are globally applicable to everywhere easily)

Comment: There's a userscript for this now: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368282/584192